# iOS make gestureRecognizer listen outside of view

Tags: android, ios

Hey I am using this code to imitate a knob view in my app:

```
- (void) setupGestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint midPoint = CGPointMake(image.frame.origin.x + image.frame.size.width / 2,
                                   image.frame.origin.y + image.frame.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat outRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2;
    gestureRecognizer = [[OneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithMidPoint: midPoint
                                                                         innerRadius: outRadius / 10
                                                                          outerRadius: outRadius *2
                                                                              target: self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer];
}
```

Like this, the gestureRecognizer handles all the events that happen **on** or **very close** to the button. What I want is the following:

- gestureRecognizer only gets triggered when user touches **inside**
  the image
- if finger leaves the image, gestureRecognizer should continue
  listening (and calculating the angle)

On Android I am doing it like the following:

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        float x = e2.getX() / ((float) getWidth());
        float y = e2.getY() / ((float) getHeight());
        float rotDegrees = cartesianToPolar(1 - x, 1 - y);

        [...doing maths stuff here]
```

I got all the rotating stuff working but how do you make the gestureRecognizer work like you can handle events in Android? If I lost my internet connection and had no choice but to code it completely on my own I would just take 2 different gestureRecognizers, on handling the "init" press and one "following" the finger everywhere, setting the correspondent knob according to the key value being set in the first gestureRecognizer. But this looks like a massive pile of bad code to me so I'd appreciate some advice on this one.

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the delegate method, `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` to examine the location of the touch, and return YES only if the touch point is within the image view's bounds (using `CGRectContainsPoint`). If the gesture recognizer is added to the image view's superview, it should continue to "listening" like you want.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.imageView.frame, touchPoint);
}
```

Also be sure to set the controller as the delegate of the gesture recognizer.

Comment: thanks mate that sounds awesome. Will try soon and let you know, enjoy your day!

Comment: update: it took me ages to realize that you also need to add  gestureRecognizer.delegate = self; when setting up the gestureRecognizer and you may wanna add this to your answer but thanks so much man!